# Meaning of capital $S$ in Student's "The Probable Error of a Mean"

Tags: standard-deviation, notation, t-distribution

I'm reading through Student's "The Probable Error of a Mean" from 1908 and I'm not sure what notation he is using. He says that if $s$ is the standard deviation from a sample $x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n$ then $s^2 = \frac{S(x_1^2)}{n}-\left( \frac{S(x_1)}{n} \right)^2 = \frac{S(x_1^2)}{n} - \frac{S(x_1^2)}{n^2} - \frac{2S(x_1x_2)}{n^2}$. I'm not sure what capital $S$ represents here. I'd suspect it has something to do with sample standard deviation, but then I don't know why the equation only references $x_1$ and $x_2$ when there are $n$ variables.

Comment: See https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/14678

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S$ is meant here as *summation.* $S(x_1^2) $ means the sum of squares of the sample observations initiating from $x_1^2.$ Similarly, in the same vein, with $S(x_1x_2). $

Now, is this universally used?

Well, I am not the authority here but one thing I can assert is that this is an unusual usage and quite arcane.

However, with that being said, usage of $S$ for summation is not even that of a rarity. For example, in $\rm [I], $ the author in order to distinguish the sample from population used $\sf S$ reserving $\sum$ for population:

\begin{align}\textrm{summation over the units}&~~~\mathsf S_{i=1}^n\\\textrm{summation over cross-products}&~~~\mathsf S_{i=1}^n\mathsf S_{j\ne i}^n.\end{align}

I'm not sure when the usage started (that's for history sleuths to check) but it is certainly not in tune today.

---

### Reference:

$\rm [I]$ Sampling Theory and Methods, *M. N. Murthy,* Statistical Publishing Society, $1967,$ sec. $2.14, $ p. $51.$

Comment: $S$ for sum has now (at least in my reading) quite faded away, but it took a long time to fade away. For example, it can be found in the first (1925) edition of FIsher's _Statistical Methods for Research Workers_. An advantage until well into the 20th century was that it was easy to type on a typewriter.  There was a time before $\TeX$.....

Comment: That's a valid pointer @NickCox.

Comment: So $S(x_1 x_2)$ would be $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(x_i x_{i+1})$?

Comment: @Vityou It would be $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j>i}^n x_ix_j.$